# What is Facebook's database schema for messages like?

Tags: database-design, facebook

How does Facebook structure their data for messages.  I have heard they use Cassandra for inbox search, but is this the only technology they use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how the [Facebook database schema](http://www.flickr.com/photos/ikhnaton2/533233247/sizes/o/) *might* look like.

I doubt it *actually* looks like this, because such a normalized scheme wouldn't be very scalable. Check out [Data Management, Facebook-style](http://20bits.com/articles/data-management-facebook-style/).

Comment: Why would a normalized schema not be scalable? I thought data normalization was exactly the requirement for scalable databases.

Comment: I think you are confusing the two terms (normalization and denormalization). As for a few reasons why the scheme is not scalable, take a look here: http://www.25hoursaday.com/weblog/CommentView.aspx?guid=cc0e740c-a828-4b9d-b244-4ee96e2fad4b

Comment: I think the question was about the "messaging" system. The schema you linked to doesn not contain messages.